# Wrong format in Kendo Time Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

**Html**

```
<input id="timepicker" />
```

**KendoTimePicker(javascript)**

```
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
                        format: "HH:mm",
                        change: function () {
                            var value = this.value();
                            console.log("value is the selected date in the timepicker");
                            console.log(value);
                            alert(value);
                        }
  });
```

Now, my issue is when I change the KendoTimePicker value, its not coming in HH:mm format but in the following format:

Mon May 15 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Please click here : [JS Fiddle Url](http://jsfiddle.net/RZEga/182/)

Answer (score 0):

By [default](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker#methods-value), `this.value()` will be represented as an instance of Javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

However, you can extract the specific time value from the `value` through the use of various different methods:

- [getHours](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gethours.asp)
- [getMinutes](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getminutes.asp)
- [getUTCHours](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getutchours.asp) (if time required according to UTC)
- [toLocaleTimeString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) (if time required in a specific locale)
- [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) plugin (which would be my personal favourite) - included a small snippet below:

```js
var result = moment().format('hh:mm');
alert(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse to string:

```
var data = [];
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    change: function() {
            alert(kendo.toString(this.value(),"hh:mm tt"))
    }
});
```

Note: use tt at format to show AM/PM. With tt -> 02:30 AM, without -> 02:30. Also if u want 0 - 24 sacale use HH:mm format.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaandric/fu0u5qo8/)

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this, but in controller, iam still getting this format: Mon May 15 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as after selecting the time value from the kendoTimePicker and tabbing out (onBlur) the values get into the format

```
  Mon May 15 2017 07:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

So this was the fix

Cell definition in the div grid (timeShowinghtml.cfm)

```
{ 'field': 'starttime', 'title': 'Start Time', 'width': 120,'editor': editorStartTimeGrid,'format': '{0:HH:mm tt}' }
```

modelJsForGrid.js

function editorStartTimeGrid(container, options) {
    $('')

```
 .appendTo(container);
 $('#txtStartTimeGrid').kendoTimePicker({
    parseFormats: ["0", "hh:mm tt"],
    animation: false,
    interval: 15,
    format: "hh:mm tt"
 });
```

I am only showing the getDataChanges event in the kendo ViewModel definition for my grid

```
getDataChanges: function() {
    var retData = [];
    jQuery.each(this.dsGridEquipment.data(), function(index, item) {

        if (item.dirty) {
            //this line converts the javaScript timestamp back to time only string
            item.starttime = toLocalTimeString(item.starttime);
            retData.push(item);
        }
    }); 
    return retData;
},
```